# sql-access: HAVING clause and != operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i am new to access sql and i built a select statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], 
       Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [CountOf1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)], 
       [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]
  FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
 WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between #9/1/2009# And #9/30/2009#))
having ([CountOf1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] != 0)
GROUP BY [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)];
```

its not liking my HAVING clause. what is wrong with it? how do i do a != ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the `HAVING` clause has to be **after** the `GROUP BY` - use:

```
  SELECT [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], 
         Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [CountOf1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)], 
         [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]
    FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
   WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between #9/1/2009# And #9/30/2009#))
GROUP BY [Lab Occurrence Form].[Practice Code], [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]
  HAVING Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) != 0);
```

Also, you typically can't use the column alias in GROUP BY/HAVING clauses.

`!=` is ANSI 92? standard, but `<>` should also work.

Comment: != may very well be ANSI 92 SQL, but it's not supported by the Access SQL92 "compatibility" mode -- only <> works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<>`. IIRC, `!=` would work in MySQL though

Comment: tried that and it didnt work, when i tried to run a query it actually asked me for the value of [CountOf1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]